# copying files from subfolders via grep shell script

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to write a shell script to do the following :
I have a folder with many subfolders. Each of these subfolders has a *.gz file and some other files which I don't need. I want to move all .gz files into a new subfolder called needed_files (I have already created this subfolder). So I did the following :
I went to the parent folder with all the subfolder and cp */*.gz > needed_files/., but this did not work. Can you suggest what I should be doing?

Comment: I tried this but get  find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

Comment: ok try: `find . -name '*.gz' -exec cp {} /needed_files/ \;`

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is irrelevant here. Use `find`:

```
find . ! \( -type d -name needed_files -prune \) -type f -name '*.gz' \
     -exec echo mv -t needed_files {} +
```

POSIX equivalent of that `-exec` is

```
-exec sh -c 'echo mv "$@" needed_files' _ {} +
```

If its output looks good, remove `echo`.

Btw I noticed that the title says *copy* but you also say *I want to move*, so decide on what you exactly want to do and let me know so I can edit my answer.